# Android listview inside list item duplicate state

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

I have ListView inside List Item. When i click on listview i get no response. I need this listview duplicate state of list item.
Image:
[image]

Here is the code:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
android:background="@android:color/white">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/kind_a_main_lay"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="10">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="5.20">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/user_name_TextView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:text="Name S."
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textIsSelectable="false" />

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/user_way_points_ListView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="90dp"
            android:divider="#00000000"
            android:dividerHeight="0dp"
            android:scrollbars="none"
            android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent"
            android:layout_below="@id/user_name_TextView">
        </ListView>


    </RelativeLayout>

 </LinearLayout>
```

```
ListView lvMain = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.main_driver_order_fragment_list);
    driverOrderListAdapter = new DriverOrderListAdapter(getActivity(), modelOrders);
    lvMain.setAdapter(driverOrderListAdapter);
    lvMain.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), DriverChatListActivity.class);
            getActivity().startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

How i can do this listview clickable as part of list item?

Thank you!

Comment: Can you share java code ?

Comment: I believe that there is a problem to nest 2 list views like that. Why don't you offer possibility to click on first list and then open detail activity for this item and there you display the second list view.

Comment: @sylsau I have to do this way

Comment: I don't think that nesting two listview is a good idea. if the nested listview will have a max number of three itens, you should use a LinearLayout instead

Comment: @RenanLopesFerreira There can be from 3 to 6 elements, in this case list view not a bad idea